# How to handle uppercase keystrokes in SDL?

Tags: c++, unicode, event-handling, sdl, uppercase

How to get SDL to understand the difference between tapping a letter with *caps lock on and caps lock off*, or, *shift + 'a' = 'A'*, or that *shift + '1' = '!'*...etc?

Answer (score 0):

First add this command:

```
SDL_EnableUNICODE(SDL_ENABLE);
```

which basically allows SDL to recognise the difference between Uppercase and Lowercase and even the difference between holding Shiftand and a character (like shift + 'a' = 'A' or shift + '1' = '!').
After that , assuming you know how to extract regular keys (`event.key.keysym.sym`), just use `event.key.keysym.unicode` instead.

#### Example

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

string stringinput()
{
    string input;
    SDL_EnableUNICODE( SDL_ENABLE );
    SDL_Event uin;
    while(!(uin.type==SDL_KEYDOWN&&uin.key.keysym.sym==SDLK_RETURN))
    {
        while(SDL_PollEvent(&uin))
        {
            if(uin.type==SDL_KEYDOWN)
            {
                if((uin.key.keysym.unicode>='A'&&uin.key.keysym.unicode<='Z')
                ||(uin.key.keysym.unicode>='a'&&uin.key.keysym.unicode<='z')
                ||(uin.key.keysym.unicode>='0'&&uin.key.keysym.sym<='9')
                ||(uin.key.keysym.unicode==SDLK_SPACE))
                {
                    input+=((char)uin.key.keysym.unicode);
                }
                else
                {
                    switch((unsigned int)uin.key.keysym.unicode)
                    {
                    case SDLK_BACKSPACE:
                        input.erase(input.size()-1);
                    break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    SDL_EnableUNICODE( SDL_DISABLE );
    return input;
}
int main()
{
    string mystring=stringinput();
    cout<<mystring;
    while(1);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

SDL no longer supports `SDL_EnableUNICODE()`. Here is how to get Text Input that differentiates between upper and lowercase letters with SDL2 - [from the wiki](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL2/Tutorials-TextInput):

```
#include "SDL.h"

extern char *text;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    SDL_bool done = SDL_FALSE;

    SDL_StartTextInput();
    while (!done) {
        SDL_Event event;
        if (SDL_PollEvent(&event)) {
            switch (event.type) {
                case SDL_TEXTINPUT:
                    /* Add new text onto the end of our text */
                    strcat(text, event.text.text);
                    break;
            }
        }
 
    }
    SDL_StopTextInput();
    return 0;
}
```